# Issue with custom attributes in child views when parent layout has specified own theme

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm trying to solve an odd problem where in my layout xml file a parent view (`<LinearLayout>`) has an attribute called `android:theme="@style/blueTheme"` and it's children (`<TextView>`) have `android:background=?attr/backgroundColor`.

The issue here is that the returned attribute has no value. I've expected that the value would be retrieved from it's parent theme (ie. `@style/blueTheme`) but can't just make it to work.

Is this feature supported at all?

edit-

```
<style name="blueTheme">
    <item name="backgroundColor">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

and the `backgroundColor` is defined as
`<attr name="backgroundColor" format="reference" />`

Comment: Could you post the `blueTheme` style definition? I suspect the problem is that `backgroundColor` is not an attribute defined for themes.

Comment: updated it but to me it looks good

Comment: Does it work if you change the `attr` definition to `format="color"` ?

Comment: no it doesn't. It randomly started to work - but then I've cleared the project (clean & invalidate cached and restart from Android Studio) and it stopped to work.

Comment: Yeah, everything looks good to me as well. Some things I'd try to test: what happens if you set the activity's theme (rather than just the parent view)? What does the definition of `@color/blue` look like?

Comment: Color was `#ff0000ff`. Anyway I think i found a solution - I have changed the theme name from `blueTheme` to `blueTheme2` and it started to work. I'm guessing some build cache issue although i clearly remember removing everything (/build, gradle clear, Android Studio invalidate caches).